# Get text from a GtkEntry

Tags: c, gtk

I'm getting a segmentation fault trying to compile the following code. My question is, Is this the correct way to get text from a GtkEntry?. If it is, Why am I getting the segmentation fault?. If it´s not, What´s the correct way to retrieve text from a GtkEntry?.

```
void dialogoIngresarDados(GtkWidget *window){
GtkWidget *dialog;
GtkWidget *vbox, *button;
GtkWidget *hBoxDado1, *hBoxDado2, *label1, *label2;
struct textEntries dados;

dialog = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(dialog),5);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(dialog ,200, 100);
gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(dialog), "Dados");
gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(dialog), FALSE);

vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);

label1 = gtk_label_new("Dado1");
label2 = gtk_label_new("Dado2");
button = gtk_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_APPLY);

dados.entryDado1 = gtk_entry_new_with_max_length(10);
dados.entryDado2 = gtk_entry_new_with_max_length(10);

hBoxDado1 = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE,0);
hBoxDado2 = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE,0);

gtk_box_pack_start_defaults (GTK_BOX (vbox), hBoxDado1);
gtk_box_pack_start_defaults (GTK_BOX (vbox), hBoxDado2);
gtk_box_pack_start_defaults (GTK_BOX (vbox), button);

gtk_box_pack_start_defaults (GTK_BOX (hBoxDado1), label1);
gtk_box_pack_start_defaults (GTK_BOX (hBoxDado1), dados.entryDado1);

gtk_box_pack_start_defaults (GTK_BOX (hBoxDado2), label2);
gtk_box_pack_start_defaults (GTK_BOX (hBoxDado2), dados.entryDado2);

gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(dialog), vbox);

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(applyIngresarDados), &dados);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(dialog), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

gtk_widget_show_all (dialog);
}
```

Clicked signal callback.

```
void applyIngresarDados(GtkButton *button, struct textEntries *dados){
const gchar *dado1;
const gchar *dado2;

dado1 = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(dados->entryDado1));
dado2 = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(dados->entryDado2));
}
```

Structure containing the text entries.

```
struct textEntries{
GtkWidget *entryDado1;
GtkWidget *entryDado2;
};
```

Comment: Have you ran the code in a debugger? What line exactly is causing the segfault?

Comment: The gtk_entry_get_text() function is causing the segfault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(applyIngresarDados), &dados);
```

you pass a pointer to a dados structures, which is stack-allocated:

```
struct textEntries dados;
```

This is wrong, because when the structure is used in a callback, the stack frame containing this structure is destroyed and is probably overwritten by some other data. You're trying to access garbage data in a callback handler.

Comment: Then what is the correct way to do so? Its valuable to mention here the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You callback signature should be like this

```
gboolean appCallBack(GtkWidget*,gpointer);
```

You can typecast the gpointer to the structure of your type.
Please create a entry using API `gtk_entry_new().` I have not found any reference in gtk+2.0 documentation for `gtk_entry_new_with_max_length`.

```
GtkWidget *entry;
entry = gtk_entry_new();
```

Now in your appCallback the function can get the entry text as follows.

```
GtkWidget *entry = (GtkWidget *) callback_data; //data passed in signal connect.
```

Then you can get the text from this entry with the call

```
gchar *text;
text = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry));
```

Also do the proper error checks.

Or you can declare the textentries structure as a pointer.

Comment: gtk_entry_new_with_max_length exists, but it is deprecated since Gtk-2.0 and should not be used in newly written code.

Comment: @Dmitry-Well in that case i think problem exists with the callback signature and the pointer for holding the widgets.

Comment: Changing the gpointer to another type of pointer the way I did also works.

Comment: @Dallen- It will work but to maintain consistency you have to follow a pattern. Sometimes you may want to use a same callback connected for different signals over same or different widget with different user data. 
Otherwise also its good to have uniformity.

Comment: I completely agree with you, but this time is was just looking for a fast solution. And the signal won´t be connected in other way.